# Rxjs - combine 2 streams and only emit if previous true

Tags: rxjs

Is there way to emit only if previous value is true and do it in a **serial fashion**?

For example (but not using race):

```
 race(this.firstObservable$, this.secondObservable$).subscribe(
      //do Something
    );
```

But I don't want secondObservable to be called if firstObservable returns false.

Comment: What do you mean by `serial fashion` ? `don't want secondObservable to be called` - to be _called_, do you mean to be subscribed or to emit a value?

Comment: Subscribed. For example it’s an API call that I don’t want to be called at all.

Comment: Have you tried something like `concat(first$.pipe(filter(v => !!v)), second$)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the first value of the observable, and if the value is `true`, then [switchMapTo](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmapto) the second stream:

```js
this.firstObservable$.pipe(
  filter(v => v === true),
  switchMapTo(this.secondObservable$)
);
```

Comment: This will only work for the first emit. It wont block the secondObservable from emitting after the pipe switched to it for once.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag it's intentional

Comment: Alright. Then sorry. I interpreted the requirements differently. If it's intentional, then this solution is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some variant of `mergeMap` to handle it. @eliya-cohen's answer is one option, an alternative would be to do:

```
this.firstObservable.pipe(
  // If the source will only ever return one value then this is not necessary
  // but this will stop the first observable after the first value
  take(1), 
  // Flattens to an empty observable if the value is not truthy
  flatMap(x => iif(() => x, this.secondObservable$))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use `filter` operator and then use one of the high-order observable operator `switchMap` (unsub from the previous inner observable), `mergeMap` (keep previous inner observable sub), [etc.](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) (depending on your needs)

```js
this.firstObservable$.pipe(
  filter(Boolean),
  // be carefull here and instead switchMapTo use lazy alternative - switchMap
  switchMap(() => this.secondObservable$) 
);
```

Comment: This only works for the first emits until the secondObservable fires. Then the filter will only avoid emitting the firstObservable again.

Comment: No, there are no unsub operators like `take`, `first`, `takeUntil`. So I don't see any reasons why it couldn't works after first emit. This filter just helps us to avoid false value from outer (first) observable, it's desired behavior. if outer obs fires with true -> we unsub from prev inner observable and create new one subscription

Comment: Maybe I understood the requirements wrong here. I thought @KingKongFrog want's to avoid emitting the second observable in general if the first one emits false.